# Add text to speak before announcing label's text

Tags: ios, uilabel, voiceover

I have a label in my app that the user should be able to tap on with VoiceOver enabled to have it speak the text of that label. However, I want it to always say something before it reads the label's text. I tried to set the `accessibilityLabel` via `self.displayLabel.accessibilityLabel = "my text here" + self.displayLabel.text!` but this results in it always being set to the label's original text value which is always changing in this app.

How can I add text to announce just before the label's content, ensuring it will always speak the label's current text contents?

Comment: why cant u append text to that label before assigning?

Comment: Update it each time the label text changes (and consider posting an announcement or layout change notification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `accessibilityLabel` property in the `UILabel` subclass to return whatever you'd like.

```
override var accessibilityLabel: String! {
    get {
        return "my text here" + "," + self.text!
    }
    set { }
}
```

You may want to post an announcement each time the text changes to inform VO users the value has changed.

Comment: Isn't it 'super.accessibilityLabel = newValue' in the setter instead? That code seems to go in a recursive infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnDifool You are right. You can leave the setter empty. Thanks